# How can I eliminate the Matlab error: "converstion to double from struct is not possible"?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to read multiple images in order to generate a movie in Matlab. So, I use this code:

```
M = zeros(1,10); 

for i = 1:10 
    images = sprintf('img%d.jpg',i);
    ImageData = imread(images); 
    M(i) = im2frame(ImageData); 
end 

movie(M)

movie2avi(M,'sonar.avi','compression','None','fps',6,'quality',100)
```

But I get the following error:

```
"The following error occurred converting from struct to double:

Error using double

Conversion to double from struct is not possible.

Error in open83B_edited_2 (line 295)

M(i) = im2frame(ImageData);"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, `M` is an array of double, so you cannot assign a structure (the result of `im2frame`) to a double.

It seems that you should not try to allocate the frame stack `M`; you don't even need to declare `M`, this variable will be automatically created and the struct array will expand each iteration. Delete the first line and it will works fine.